# Using ignore to skip one to two lines

Tags: c++

I'm trying to skip the first line from an input file, and possibly a second line.

```
    //Ignore first line, second if begins with #
in.ignore(256, '\n');
char c = in.peek();
if(c == '#') 
    in.ignore(256, '\n');

//read in all nums, including x, y, gs
while(in >> num) {
    pic.push_back(num);
}
```

My problem is, nothing is getting pushed back into pic. Am I using ignore correctly?

Comment: You are using `256` as a magic number but it isn't. The magic number indicating that as many characters as needed are to be skipped is `std::nimeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max()`.

Comment: You could possibly get better alternatives if you show us your input stream (the file contents)

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code under two cases.

1. The first line is shorter than `256` characters. In this case, it works corectly.
2. The first line is longer than `256` characters. In this case, it breaks.

However, using the fix suggested by DietmarKuhl, the code no longer breaks:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

using namespace std;
int main(){
    cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    char c = cin.peek();
    if(c == '#') 
        cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');

    int num;

    //read in all nums, including x, y, gs
    while(cin >> num) {
        cout << num << endl;;
    }
}
```